# Call to a member function save() on array, when i tried to update the data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, visual-studio-code

Hey so I'm trying to change data and update them. But this error shows up when I press update button: "Call to a member function save() on array"
So this is my code:

Controller:

```
public function update(Request $r)
{
     
    $update_id = $r->uid;

    $name = $r->uname;
    $email = $r->umail;
    $add = $r->uadd;

    $update =  App\Models\Emp_model::find($update_id);

    $update['name']=$name;
    $update['email']=$email;
    $update['address']=$add;

    $updated=$update->save();

    if ($updated) {
        return redirect('show')->with('message', 'Data added successfully!');
    }
    
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/show', [Employee::class, 'fetch']);
Route::post('/update_data', [Employee::class, 'update']);
```

Action:

```
<form action="{{ url('/update_data') }}" method="post">
```

Comment: are you sure that this is the code that is been run?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Because `Emp_model::find($udpate_id)` has returned null. first check on that. either there is no matching records in the database or this is not the primary key.

Comment: Id is primary key

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use simply the `update` method:

```
$el =  App\Models\Emp_model::find($update_id);

$el->update([
    'name' => $name ,
    'email' => $email ,
    'address' => $add ,
]);
```

Comment: This is what showed up after this code: Call to a member function update() on null

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the `$r->uid` does not correspond to the primary key column for the model. So you can try the below

```php
public function update(Request $r)
{
    <!-- Replace uid with whatever is the column name -->
    $employee = App\Models\Emp_model::where('uid', $r->uid)->firstOrFail();

    $employee->update([
        'name' => $r->uname,
        'email' => $r->uemail,
        'add' => $r->uadd,
    ]);

    return redirect('show')->with('message', 'Data added successfully!');    
}
```

You can have a named route for update with the id as route parameter

```php
Route::post('/update_data/{id}', [Employee::class, 'update'])->name('emp.update');
```

Then in the blade view for edit

```
<!-- Replace $emp with whatever is the variable name -->
<form action="{{ route('emp.update', ['id' => $emp->id]) }}" method="post">
```

Comment: Hey thanks, its not showing any error with the method anymore but its showing 404 not found.

Comment: Check if there exists a record in the database corresponding to the value of `$r->uid`. The `firstOrFail()` method checks for the record matching the where condition and if it doesn't find any record it throws ModelNotFound exception which returns a 404 HTTP status. So in the update method if no record is found in db for `$r->uid` it stops execution beyond the line with `firstOrFail()`

Comment: Ok so the column is id, and i changed the uid from your code to id and then the 404 showed up.

Comment: I mean this part: $employee = App\Models\Emp_model::where('id', $r->uid)->firstOrFail(); , and uid uname uemail are called in blade.php file

Comment: You can try `dd($r->all());` as the first line in the update method and see what is the value for uid then check if a record for that id exists in the database

Comment: array:5 [▼
  "_token" => "Zeysm2RNvK4AyD9YUdwr2gZhEKG71yoXT7v63QhW"
  "uid" => null
  "uname" => "genci"
  "umail" => "mehmeti.genci5@gmail.com"
  "uadd" => "Mount Tabor, 1517"
]

Comment: Yes place `dd($r->all());` as the very first line in the method. dd means die and dump - it will just get the value for $r->all() and stop execution and dump the value on screen. It's useful for quick debugging. As the dump shows the uid value is null in the request so it can't find a record. Check the form from where you are posting to the route

Comment: "uid" => null  , All other datas are defined except id

Comment: Means that uid value is not passed from the form. You can have a hidden input with name=uid and value=<id of the record being edited> or you can have a route parameter in the route and pass the id as route parameter. Have updated the answer to include named route with route parameter. Edit your question to include the complete form code

Comment: Omg im so bad... I messed up the code now :(

Comment: You need to catch up on the basics of Laravel. Official Laravel documentation is a good source and laracasts.com probably has free series of video tutorials for the basics check out https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch

Comment: Yeah but i have only 1 and a half week to do this project and win an internship place. This is the first 3 days of me coding on Laravel.

Comment: In that case Laracasts series is your best bet. Spend a day or two thoroughly watching the series, it will help you get the basics right. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
function update(Request $r)
{
    $update = Emp_model::find($r->uid);
    $update->uname=$r->uname;
    $update->umail=$r->umail;
    $update->uadd=$r->uadd;
    
    $updated=$update->save();

    if ($updated) {
        return redirect('show')->with('message', 'Data added successfully!');
    }
}
```

Comment: Attempt to assign property "name" on null;  and after you fix this problem will go back at save() error

Comment: your fetch function not add to the controller

Comment: public method remove that on your function check update function

Comment: check code run if you have other error so pleas inform me i can solved them.

Answer (score 0):

Routes:

```
Route::get('show/{id}', [Employee::class, 'fetch']);
Route::post('update_data', [Employee::class, 'update']);
```

Action:

```
<form action="/update_data" method="post">
```